# Displaying text in Stream builder in flutter using user id from authentication

Tags: flutter

```
body: StreamBuilder(         
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('students').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return  Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 100,
                       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: new SizedBox(
                            width: 180.0,
                            height: 180.0,
                            child: (_image!=null)?Image.file(
                            _image,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ):
                          Image.network(
                            '$_downloadurl.jpg',
                            fit:  BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.camera,
                        size: 30.0,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        getImage();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:40.0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text('Student Name',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0)),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(snapshot.data.id['first_name'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                      )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I want to display text using user id in stream builder align text[here is my database image and i i want to access the a specific user in students collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ImB.png)
if there is any other function to convert it please help me

when I run the code only one user's data is retrieved even then the data of not logged in user is also retrieved

Comment: What you actually want ?

Comment: i want to display details of only single user who is logged in using document id

Answer (score 0):

i would opt for a `ListView.builder` here is how you can implement it

load data from cloud firestore in your initState

```
getData()async{
  return Firestore.instance.collection('students').getDocuments();
 }
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;
   @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
    getData().then((results) {
     setState(() {
    querySnapshot = results;
          });
        });
       }`
```

display data in your listview

```
    Widget _users(){
    if(querySnapshot!=null){
      return ListView.builder(
              // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: querySnapshot.documents.length,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
//show data from snapshot
              return Text("${querySnapshot.documents[i].data['email']}");
                   }
    }
}
```

in your body add the widget `_users` eg `Container(child:_users)`